# About integer factorization

Tags: factoring

Let $N=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are safe primes. If the adversary knows the inverse of $p$ mod $q$ and the inverse of $q$ mod $p$, can this help him factor $N$ or break the textbook RSA?

Comment: Well the point is that you can't calculate $p \bmod q$ because you don't have $p$ and $q$, or did I understand something wrong in your question?

Comment: The adversary is assumed to know $p^{-1}\bmod q$. But is s/he assumed to additionally know $q^{-1}\bmod p$, or $q\bmod p$ ? The [question (v2)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/68648/2) can be read either way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $q^{-1} \bmod p$ is meant; if you know $q \bmod p$ (where $q < p$), well, that fairly obviously gives the game away...

Answer (score 4):

Santanu Sarkar and Subhamoy Maitra show in [Some Applications of Lattice Based Root Finding Techniques](https://ia.cr/2010/146) the deterministic polynomial time equivalence between factoring $N$ ($N=p\cdot q$, where $p>q$ or $p,q$ are of same bit size) and knowledge of $q^{−1} \bmod p$ (cited from the abstract).

Comment: I should have mentioned that they use a variation of the "usual" Coppersmith techniques.