# Can the knowledge of the inverse of $p$ modulo $q$ help factor $n=pq$?

Tags: rsa

With the RSA algorithm implemented using the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT), the private key has to be provided with not only $p$, $q$ and the private exponent $d$, but often also with the pre-computed value $q^{-1} \bmod p$ for a faster recombination using the CRT.

Assuming that $q^{-1} \bmod p$ is leaked to the adversary (but not $d$, $p$ and $q$ themselves), does that help factor $n = pq$? And if so, how?

Comment: By an entropy argument, $q^{-1} \bmod p$ reveals in the order of $\log_2(N)/2$ bit of entropy, which is about twice as much as needed from $p$ or $q$ to factor $N$ in several known attacks factoring $N$, Therefore, it would not be surprising is there was an efficient method to factor $N$ given $q^{-1} \bmod p$. In fact, I would be surprised is there was no such method. But this is not an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About integer factorization](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68648/about-integer-factorization)

Comment: @patriot: this is not a duplicate, since the other question supposes that $p^{-1} \bmod q$ is known in addition to $q^{-1} \bmod p$, and that $p$ and $q$ are safe primes. Anything that solves the present question also solves the other one, but not vice versa. The [answer there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68660/555) helps, but does not cover $p$ of lower bit size than $q$.

Comment: The answer is duplicate, but the question is not exactly a duplicate. [That question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68648/about-integer-factorization) is more restrictive, i.e., the primes are supposed to be safe primes and the adversary knows both $q^{-1} \bmod p$ **and** $p^{-1} \bmod q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was already answered in [this not-so-great titled question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68648/about-integer-factorization).

($p$ and $q$ being "safe primes" does not matter in this context, but $q$ shouldn't be (much) longer than $p$, as the methods works for $q<p$, but can be adapted by "guessing" the top bits of $q$ otherwise).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and thanks for asking this question back in 2009! :-)