# Decrypt RSA knowing N, invp, and invq

Tags: encryption, rsa, keys

im having a problem while solving a RSA problem, so i have python script to create a RSA key and cipher, from that i have n, invp, and invq. so my question is possible to decrypt the message only with n, invp, and invq.
Here's the code

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

message = bytes('seccreeetttt', encoding='utf-8')
key = RSA.generate(2048)
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
ct = cipher.encrypt(message)
print(key.n)
print(key.invp)
print(key.invq)
print(ct)
```

and the output

````
22952552825037553208589096165242660277079814094183276873079909851943463036945153387557183758316294729416133670713705132869462243363747798232032671654074637605107951710393834048681471811567952254060023385215009569538631071930055199744636956039654006517651206255269080364046092411668611132590129579259270927581325624773795643855705850358939883724406306418820717111487692856281516614051094114705929121423407101332088124042150889509501597216327824776884748412486585968553561814684440822170007044907888709866179060881286334778923820553288711054581803265605135021930549004917176478076658295939298440410800453610420784514457
163882732681011974117964095241512724964174035813367591706325214234200287217436607411780964390312708482743593138034867229898010005380965207066160414127619082907877801827298833620891890898399317834648975726792134305597419952280242983199611380599923775647406646313572445197360361496233777371466832268309751027400
8199057223758240152335562983205355098470471408203502855692459583092981421137253285881215078560856677573652286387349952842606605032529999529740761548782764321969094758106790305148212636865417002195134316934877626601994849828699145449072737101068731796017218203705313864472498801699218279579743987247107819566
b'\x7f\xa2\t\xf1\xe0B\xa8OK\x9a\xde\xc7o\x9c4]\xealz\x98\x14\x99xN\xdc9\xd4\xaa\x90\xdc2:\x1d\xdb:i\xa7\x82\xe0\xd5S\xf8\x10\x93\x1dh\xc1:\xee5\xc6\xf641,\xa0B\x8e?N\xbd_\xcb\x9f\x0e\xf1>\xda\xe8^{\x99d.,\xcf\xca\xd1zHGt\xcd\xcf\x06"\x7f\xf6z\xb8\xa8\x14\xa8\xab\xec8\xe3\x81\xa5\xc3Bt\x8a`\xee\x9b\xb7\xf3}~\x88\x89y!\xc2\xe3\xeb\xda\xdc;\xbe\xea\x1ez\x03L\xf9\xf6v\x03\xe1[\x9eL\x9e\xd7\x0e~7t"q\x18\xa6Q\x15\xc8>[:\xc0>\xd7\xcdpng\xf38\r*\x1e\xfc\x0fc\xc1YQ\xf6\xb9B\x8f\x98\x04\xc0\xc3Y\x10\xb93[\x15\xb7\xc1CT\x12\xbb\xcc0\xcb\xb5\xae\xad\xe9\x04\x00TC{\t0\xfc\xe8\x89\x8c\xf2_q\t\xda\xcd \xb3\xce\x84\x1eK\\\xae\x98\x0e_g\xd8\xf6\xcfB\x19\xa8\xe0\xdfos\x96\x8a\xede\xc7\x0f\x91\xbe/\xbav~\x8a)\xcc\xe1\x1b\xb7\xf5\xbe"\xe8'
```
````

Comment: HINT: [Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.Generate’](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.generate) defaults to an encryption exponent 65537. This allows you to generate arbitrary matched plain and cipher.

Comment: It's possible, but not trivial. Mostly already answered in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68648